# reactjs: frontend: security: can some one tweek with conditionally rendered content and get access to unauthorized pages

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a subscription site with reactjs as front end.

The user can have 3 types of subscription

Since reactjs app is a single page app, all the code is loaded into the browser.

Now based on some variables like `isSubscritionCategory1` then I will show certain elements, etc

So someone who knows developement tools can go and change the variable values and run it and see the other subscription content also

So what is the general advise in such cases, even admin only pages etc.

Solution i feel is everytime keep calling the subscription type from backend for the use (using user token as authentication). So even someone changes the code, it will revert back.

But calling everytime the backend to get the subscription type will fail the point of using reactjs as single page app.

Comment: Are you shipping "sensitive" data with the app when it loads, or are sensitive resources protected in the back end and only accessible via tokenization/etc?

Comment: NO sensitive data is loaded, but want to know whether the only way to secure is through the backend vlidation

Comment: The only true way to 100% prevent someone from messing with front end code to gain access to pages they shouldn't is to split the route code into different files and serve them from the backend from routes that are protected by authentication.

Comment: Just assume if the data is *ever* loaded/fetched on the device that it *isn't* secure. Secure access to the resources, and for what is sent to the app try to minimize exposure, i.e. don't persist to local storage, keep in memory, etc... you can go down a rabbit hole trying to monkey patch all the ways an authenticated user can use their physical device.

Comment: Just found a nice article on this https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-frontend-security-4963d35feea7